# SQL: combine 2 columns in one table to compare with 1 column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in MSSQL one is called [DATA] and the other one is called [2020]

IN [2020] I have user info for example: name , ID, adress, and so on.
IN [DATA] I have multiple columns that I need to show about the users

the catch is that I have no common column between those tables, in [2020] I have ID and adress, in [DATA] I have that info in one column called ID-adress

SO I tried this

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.Nro,
    A.name,
    A.adress,
    B.CGE AS 'GE',
    B.CGG as 'GG',
    B.CPE AS 'PE'

FROM 
    [202009] A
    LEFT JOIN [DATA] B ON str(A.ID )+'-'+cast(A.adress as varchar) = B.[ID-adress]
```

But I get NULL on the columns that I want to show on B ¿what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You might try `cast(A.ID as varchar(20))` rather than `str()`.

Comment: @shawnt00 coment was the answer! thanks a lot. write it down so I can upvote and choose as the correct answer

Comment: I may have been first to suggest that. But you can feel free to accept another answer. No reason for me to add to the list. Glad it worked.

Comment: Both @Gordon and I have answers that are equivalent in converting A.ID to a string. All will perform about the same I believe. Mine was first, while Gordon's is the cleanest/clearest.

Comment: ok @seanb fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your rather sparse description, I would guess that the `JOIN` condition never evaluates to true.

Based on the naming of the columns, you may want:

```
FROM [202009] A LEFT JOIN
     [DATA] B
     ON CONCAT(A.ID, '-', A.adress) = B.[ID-adress]
```

This is speculation based on a reasonable interpretation of the question.

There are two potential problems with your construct:

1. `str()` tends to pad values with spaces.
2. `varchar` without a length has a default length depending on context that may not be sufficient for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for debug: add your expression (`str(A.ID )+'-'+cast(A.adress as varchar)`) in your SELECT to see whether results are what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Your immediate issue, I believe, is that your string functions `str(A.ID )+'-'+cast(A.adress as varchar)` have several problems.

I suggest just putting that SQL fragment into a SELECT to see what you get (e.g.,

```
SELECT A.ID, A.adress, str(A.ID )+'-'+cast(A.adress as varchar) 
FROM [202009] A
```

to see what results you get.

I believe

- The ID is numeric (int, probably). str(A.ID) will usually put leading spaces before it, and when comparing strings, `'   5'` is different from `'5'`. Put an LTRIM in front of it e.g., `ltrim(str(A.ID))`
- `cast(A.adress as varchar)` needs a length of the varchar e.g., cast(A.adress as varchar(100)). If you don't do this, it assumes length 1.

To check, run a similar statement as above, but with fixes

```
SELECT A.ID, A.adress, ltrim(str(A.ID))+'-'+cast(A.adress as varchar(100)) 
FROM [202009] A
```

However (and I don't like to say this), but this design is ... problematic. For example, What happens when a user changes their address? All fields in the data table will be unusable.

The biggest-bang-for-buck fix (imo) is to have 2 separate fields in the Data table for `ID` and `address`. If needed, you can still keep your single field as well (ID-address).

As you say, make sure they have common columns.

Once you have the two fields, you can join them on fields that at least match to get the relevant data rows for that address e.g.,

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.Nro,
    A.name,
    A.adress,
    B.CGE AS 'GE',
    B.CGG as 'GG',
    B.CPE AS 'PE'

FROM 
    [202009] A
    LEFT JOIN [DATA] B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.adress = B.adress
```

And then, if you just want all the data rows for a given user, you can do the same thing but do not join on address (just A.ID = B.ID).

Note that this won't fix all the issues (e.g., when an address in one table is different from the other table because of things like spaces, or 'St' vs 'Street') - but will be a good start.